# Elixir GenServer best way to cast to other nodes

Tags: elixir

I have the following functions inside my GenServer:

```
def add_event(param1, param2) do
    Enum.each(:pg2.get_members("some_group"), fn pid -> GenServer.cast(pid, {:new_event, param1, param2}) end)
  end

  def handle_cast({:new_event, param1, param2}, state) do
    #do something
    {:noreply, state}
  end
```

My idea is that whenever `add_event` is called i want to cast this request to all members of the group in the others nodes. My question is, is it good idea to cast directly inside the public api or its better to do it inside the `handle_cast` callback

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand you question, but it seems to me that you do not have the choice: you need the pid to dispatch between the different members of `some_group` . Once you used the pid and genserver cast, it is in the callback. Therefore the dispatch is made inside the "public api", and the cast (the `do something`) is in the callback dispatched on every genserver (and you need to do it inside them if you use the `state`).

Comment: Actually I can do this dispaching inside the handle cast but i am not sure whether it is a good choice or not :/

Comment: You mean, you would create a GenServer (because you need a pid and a state to do the handle_cast), that is dedicated to do the dispatching ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the dispatching in a `Process` (not in the client api), implies theses pros and cons:

**pros**:

1. **Real asynchronous behaviour**: since the dispatch is on the server side, inside a `Process`, you are not going to wait after the dispatch to be done, for you `GenServer` to keep on working.
2. **Supervisor**: you can use a [Supervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html) to supervise the dispatcher.
3. **keep a state** in the dispatcher, to indicate for example: the `pid` that are called the most often, what kind of `event` is used the more often, add some logic in the dispatching..

**cons**:

1. You create two `handle_cast` instead of one: one for dispatching, and one for actually doing the job. More lines of code -> **you lose in readability**
2. Some of your process will be dedicated to dispatch, and some others will be dedicated to doing the job.. but all of them will be from the same genserver. **You have one `GenServer` for two kinds of process**
3. The process that is dedicated to dispatching the job is likely to not need maintaining a state.
4. You cannot use a different supervisor's strategy depending on the kind of process.. since the they come from the same `GenServer`

**If I had to choose**: I would do the dispatching on the "client api" side since it is a simpler pattern. If I need to maintain a state around the `call` and `cast` of my `GenServer`, I would create a second one dedicated to that.